# How to make proper "if" statement?

Tags: c#

I have a problem. I need to make two string statements to fuse into 3rd one.
I don't like how my if statement looks like.
Is it possible to make a single statement for `(A==a && B==b) || (A==b && B==a)`?
In short `(A,B)==(a,b)` disregarding order.

```
string FusionNameGet(string _name1, string _name2)
{
    string result = "Data not found";
    if (_name1 == "Test tube" && _name2 == "Holder pliers" || _name1 == "Holder pliers" && _name2 == "Test tube")
    {
        result = "TTube+HPliers";
    }
    else if (_name1 == "Clean tube" && _name2 == "Q" || _name1 == "Q" && _name2 == "Clean tube")
    {
        result = "QLuquid";
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: First of all, you need to use parenthesis to separate the ANDs and ORs.

Comment: can you tell me what is a vice versa statement?

Comment: I don´t get your problem. What exactly is whrong with your code? When you need to check multiple things, you have to write multiple conditions into if-statements of course. So what exactly do you mean by "looks like sh**"?

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow. i recommend [taking the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), as well as reading [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [what's on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: I edited the question per my understanding of *vice-versa statement*. Feel free to rollback if it is not what you meant.

Comment: @41686d6564 that is not true, operator priority makes parenthesis unnecessary in this case. I also wonder why the question got closed. There is obvious code redundancy and OP clearly tries to remove it.

Answer (score 2):

you can design the method in a better way and avoid the user to make that kind of crossing parameters when calling the method..
I mean, define enums and

```
enum TUBE
{
    TEST_TUBE,
    CLEAN_TUBE,
    YOU_TUBE
};
enum TYPE2
{
    Q,
    Holder_pliers
};
 string FusionNameGet(TUBE p1, TYPE2 p2)
 {
    if(p1==TUBE.TEST_TUBE && p2 == TYPE2.Q)
        return "TTube+HPliers";
        
    return "";
 }
```

Comment: OP is looking for an elegant way to write `(A==1 && B==2) || (A==2 && B==1)` which is not answered here

Comment: Thanks, everyone for your help! Yes, I did not receive the answer on how to elegant write if statement without redundancy, but I get the answer on how to short my code, so thank you!